# How to prevent text from moving outside the column?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

In my reactjs component I am returning this in the render():

```
<div className='col-lg-4'>
       <div className="col-lg-3">
            <img src={this.props.details.avatar} alt=""/>
       </div>
       <div className="col-lg-9 text">
       <div>
            {this.props.details.firstName}
            {this.props.details.lastName}
            {this.props.details.bio.slice(0,80)}
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Currently the this.props.details.bio which contains text overflows into the image. Which css rule can fix this issue? At the moment I have:

```
.text{
  padding:5px;
}
```

Here is a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ydxbqphw/3/)

Comment: Please provide working code.

Comment: there you go mate

Comment: You want img and img description side by side right...?

Comment: Yes that is right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The natural size of your image is larger than the bootstrap class that contains it. So what appears like the text bleeding into the image is really the image extending beyond the boundaries of its parent.

To force the image to obey the size of its parent, add this to your CSS:

```
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Please give `img-reponsive` class in `img` tag and put `col-md` and `col-sm` class. Now img and its description come side by side till  `768` screen resolution after that it is in full width.

```css
body {
    margin: 10px;
}
.main {
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: lightgrey;
    margin: 10px 10px !important;
}
.text {
    padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script><script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <noscript>
    You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.
  </noscript>
  <div id="root">
    <div>
      <div>
        <div class="row main">
          <h1>Boyer - Botsford</h1>
          <h3 class="col-lg-6">clicks-and-mortar scale infomediaries</h3>
          <h3 class="col-lg-6 text-right">Since Sat Nov 25 2017 16:55:29 GMT+1100 (AEDT)</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
              <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3"><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/buryaknick/128.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive"></div>
              <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9 text">
                <div>DylanMacdonaldAssumenda doloribus ut dolore eaque autem. Sit rem similique cum modi qui. Qui m</div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
              <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3"><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/abdullindenis/128.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive"></div>
              <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9 text">
                <div>IsabelRolfsonDicta explicabo pariatur et placeat enim. Dignissimos similique in nesciunt aut </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
              <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3"><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/andytlaw/128.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive"></div>
              <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9 text">
                <div>AnthonyCartwrightSint cum corrupti similique laudantium nesciunt aliquam sint aperiam. Id consequ</div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
              <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3"><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/longlivemyword/128.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive"></div>
              <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9 text">
                <div>LukeWestConsequatur excepturi tempore iste ipsam et architecto animi explicabo. Magnam s</div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
              <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3"><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/dnirmal/128.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive"></div>
              <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9 text">
                <div>MaxDietrichQuo dolorum et est facere nihil similique repudiandae. Recusandae ratione enim d</div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
              <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3"><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/marosholly/128.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive"></div>
              <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9 text">
                <div>AlexanderErnserSit quo dignissimos molestiae quasi ut dolor. Et et quaerat assumenda laborum ea</div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
              <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3"><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/areus/128.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive"></div>
              <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9 text">
                <div>AlyssaDanielDolor est id. Officiis aut odio molestiae ut quaerat quae vero ipsa. Voluptatem </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
              <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3"><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/alagoon/128.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive"></div>
              <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9 text">
                <div>KaiHayesNobis ea ut distinctio nam et suscipit velit. Necessitatibus exercitationem blan</div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
              <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3"><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/bertboerland/128.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive"></div>
              <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9 text">
                <div>IsabelleClarkeVel velit repellat dicta. Maxime occaecati sed dolorum et modi. Voluptates rerum</div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
              <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3"><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/drewbyreese/128.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive"></div>
              <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9 text">
                <div>HaydenWilliamsAt vel voluptatibus rerum ex aut porro. Quis dolorem qui dolorum eveniet a facer</div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
              <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3"><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/markwienands/128.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive"></div>
              <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9 text">
                <div>AbigailBorerDoloribus illum nam modi consequuntur unde et et a rerum. Laboriosam quis quod. </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
              <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3"><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/okandungel/128.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive"></div>
              <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9 text">
                <div>HamishMclaughlinSapiente aliquam consequatur doloribus occaecati dolorem perferendis qui aliquid</div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Why did you put col-sm-4, col-md-4 , they are all the same?

Comment: `col-sm-4` for tablets, 768px and up and `col-md-4` desktops, 992px and up screen.

Comment: First thing have you checked my answer...? why give down vote...? my answer is correct as community want.